# How to generate 5(more than 2) log files using 5 log4j properties in java

Tags: java

How to generate 5(more than 2) log files using 5 log4j properties in java, I done with 2 files it's working fine but I need to create more than 2 files but it's not creating more than 2 files.

Thanks.

configuration:

```
    # This is first log file

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C://First_logger.out
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[ %p ] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c:%L - %m%n%n

# This is second log file

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SecondLog

log4j.appender.SecondLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SecondLog.File=C://second-report.out
log4j.appender.SecondLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SecondLog.layout.ConversionPattern=[ %p ] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c:%L - %m%n%n

log4j.category.SecondLogger=DEBUG, SecondLog
log4j.additivity.SecondLogger=false

# This is Third log File


log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ThirdLog

log4j.appender.ThirdLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ThirdLog.File=C://third-report.out
log4j.appender.ThirdLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ThirdLog.layout.ConversionPattern=[ %p ] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c:%L - %m%n%n

log4j.category.ThirdLogger=DEBUG, ThirdLog
log4j.additivity.ThirdLogger=false
```

Comment: Any chances for switching to Logback?? https://logback.qos.ch/

Comment: Have you debug this to see where it was failing ? Is the Logger load the appenders ? Is it throwing an exception ?

Comment: I did not get any exception or error

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the problem with this configuration, the *First_logger.out* is not created but *second-report.out* and *third-report.out* are.

The three files are generated if we add the following line for the first block:

```
log4j.category.fileLogger=DEBUG, file
```

Besides, the three files are also generated if the block for the first file is put at the end of the configuration file, with the original configuration. Ath the moment, I don't know why the order of blocks matters.

Comment: Which file is not created on your side?
Is it the first one, like on mine?

If I comment the category for the three blocks, only *third-report.out* is created.

btw, I  do not have write access on *C* directory, so I am using *C://a/First_logger.out* path for my tests.

Comment: which instance is first created that 2 files are created only, for me first and second are created not third and go on.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got the solution for this. I created multiple log4j property file's but,
Actually we have to write only one log4j property file for multiple property file it not working, log4j initialize only one property file so we have to write 1 log4j file and in that file we have to configure other multiple loggers. Like below

```
    # This is only one  log4j property file

    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, SecondLog, ThirdLog

    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=C://First_logger.out
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[ %p ] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c:%L - %m%n%n

   log4j.category.fileLogger=DEBUG, file

    log4j.appender.SecondLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.SecondLog.File=C://second-report.out
    log4j.appender.SecondLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.SecondLog.layout.ConversionPattern=[ %p ] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c:%L - %m%n%n

    log4j.category.SecondLogger=DEBUG, SecondLog
    log4j.additivity.SecondLogger=false



    log4j.appender.ThirdLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.ThirdLog.File=C://third-report.out
    log4j.appender.ThirdLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.ThirdLog.layout.ConversionPattern=[ %p ] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c:%L - %m%n%n

    log4j.category.ThirdLogger=DEBUG, ThirdLog
    log4j.additivity.ThirdLogger=false
```